# Update UserControl from inside UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, updatepanel

I have a `UserControl` inside an `UpdatePanel`. I want to refresh it when a button inside the `UpdatePanel` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Register the button in updatepanel's `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>` tag.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

Or

Register the button in `ScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl()`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerasyncpostbackcontrol.aspx